# r-caret: custom model with n-dimensional output

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I am trying to fit an autoencoder model using caret. I run into problems because my output will be more than 1-dimensional (e.g. y in the call to train() will be a matrix in my case). 
Is there a way to account for output of higher dimension in caret?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, it only handles univariate outcomes. I'm not sure why you would be using `train` for an autoencoder though; those are usually used as a pre-processing step rather than the outcome itself.

Comment: Yes, but I am interested in the features that are learned given the hyperparameters. My idea was to use caret to estimate the reconstruction error.