# Tune multivariate response random forest

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

Is it possible to tune a random forest (`cforest`) with a multivariate response variable using `caret`? e.g.

```
mtry_grid <- data.frame(mtry = seq(5,50,5))
train_mtry_class <- train(Class+PRE_POST~., data=rf_data[,-c(1,2)],
                      method='cforest', tuneGrid=mtry_grid, metric='Accuracy')
```

If not, does anyone have any suggestions for tuning a random forest with a multivariate response?

Comment: Migrate to DataScience.SE for better answers

Comment: maybe outdated, but see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717969/r-caret-custom-model-with-n-dimensional-output

Answer (score 0):

There's a great CRAN package, which you can do multivariate random forest tuning:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MultivariateRandomForest/MultivariateRandomForest.pdf

Alternatively, you can use "party" (also in CRAN):
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/party/party.pdf - look at "Conditional Inference Trees"